# Which libraries for 3d surface mesh

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mesh, openni, point-cloud-library

Let me explain what i have to do:

I'm working with the **KINECT**, i want to capture the depth from the surrounding environment and creating a 3d mesh of it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 32bits, c++,  **OpenNI2 libraries** for the kinect. WIth this i can obtain a cloud of points. now i have to do the triangulation.

I read about **PCL (Point Cloud Libraries)**, but the problem is they are not compatible with OpenNI2 (or, at least, not yet).

So, what could I do? I thought different option?

1. Do the downgrade to OpenNI
2. Using a different libraries for the kinect
3. using a different libraries for creating the surface mesh

and, if I have to use different libraries, wich one you suggest me? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [kingfu largescale](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_kinfu_large_scale.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a fast and dirty solution, the best option would be 1. Downgrade to openni and use PCL. It should be relatively fast and easy.

However, if you are interested in contributing to the library, you can stay with OpenNI2 and try kinfu after [merging the OpenNI2 grabber](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/pull/276). I recommend reading comments in this PR.

It may not work just right out of the box, but you can try anyway. You'll always have option of going back to OpenNI.

Comment: but with the first version on OpenNI you think I can use the kinect? because there are different classes, and I'm not sure i can initialize hte kinect sensor and use it

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use both Kinect SDK and OpenNI? If this, then they won't work together.. at least not that simple. But there is [OpenNI Bridge](https://code.google.com/p/kinect-mssdk-openni-bridge/) you can try it. If I misunderstood you, could you please specify what do you mean by "different classes"?

Comment: my question is: is that possible to initialize kinect with openNI 1.x?

Comment: Absolutely, it is actually how things work here. Check out this [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php#openni-grabber) it should work right away, but if not, just ask I'll try to guide you.